# Run Python script through Java?

Tags: java, python, input, terminal

I am running a python script through java. Part of the code that I have so far is provided below and **successfully runs a python script that does not require user input**. It is currently displaying whatever I indicated in the python script to be printed in the terminal. I am doing this through the mac oxs terminal. However, whenever I run a python script that requires user input, it does not show anything after the "input" statement from the python script. **I need this to work with user input from the python script.**

Please help me solve this issue, thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test obj = new test();

    //in mac oxs
    String command = "python testLOL.py";
    String output = obj.executeCommand(command);
    System.out.println(output);     

}

private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        p = r.exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

        p.waitFor();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();   
}
```

Comment: It seems you have to somehow bind System.out and System.in to the process

Comment: @kamil09875 more like System.in to p.getOutputStream

Answer (score 0):

You can create two threads that bind both streams to the process

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
    executeCommand("python test/test.py");
}

private static void executeCommand(final String command){
    final Process p;
    try{
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        Thread bindIn = new Thread(() -> {
            try{
                int av;
                while(!Thread.interrupted())
                while((av = System.in.available()) > 0){
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[av];
                    System.in.read(bytes);
                    p.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
                    p.getOutputStream().flush();
                }

                System.out.println("bindIn ended");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        });

        Thread bindOut = new Thread(() -> {
            try{
                int av;
                while(!Thread.interrupted())
                while((av = p.getInputStream().available()) > 0){
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[av];
                    p.getInputStream().read(bytes);
                    System.out.write(bytes);
                }

                System.out.println("bindOut ended");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        });

        bindIn.start();
        bindOut.start();

        p.waitFor();

        bindIn.interrupt();
        bindOut.interrupt();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that now you don't need to read output at the end because it is transferred on the fly.

In your code you executed process that has its own streams so writing to `System.in` has not resulted in writing to `p.getOutputStream()` and vice versa.